# Doesn't show Users information on confirmation page

Tags: php

So I'm trying to show the username, password, and account type on confirmation page after you register.

Below is my portion from my confirmation page.  I thought if i just include functions page it would be fine since it works for other pages once you log in but it isn't showing I added `$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` to the register page at the end of post form since thats what I did for login page but it doesn't work, its saying that "username" "password" "account level" are undefined.

```
 <?php include('functions.php'); ?>
 <p>You have signed up for an account at ''.com. <br><br>
 Your username is: <b><?php echo $username ?></b> <br><br>
 Your password is: <b><?php echo $password ?></b> <br><br>
 Your Account level is: <?php echo $level_name ?></p> <br>
```

Below is my functions page, to have session for active users

```
session_start();
function loggedin(){
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

if(loggedin()) {
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT username, password, user_level, type FROM users WHERE id='$my_id'");
$run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);
$username = $run_user['username'];
$password = $run_user['password'];
$user_level = $run_user['user_level'];
$user_type = $run_user['type'];
$query_level = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM user_level WHERE id='$user_level'");
$run_level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_level);
$level_name = $run_level['name'];
}
?>
```

Below is the register page where session is set.

```
<form action = "register.php" method="POST">
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(empty($_POST['username']) 
|| empty($_POST['password'])
|| empty($_POST['email']) 
|| empty($_POST['Fname']) 
|| empty($_POST['Lname']) 
|| empty($_POST['Display1'])){

    echo '<p>Please make sure all fields are filled.</p>';

} else{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
    $Display1 = $_POST['Display1'];
    $Display2 = $_POST['Display2'];
    $userlevel = 2;
    $type = 'a';

    $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, Fname, Lname, email, Display1, Display2, user_level, type)Values('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$Fname}', '{$Lname}', '{$email}', '{$Display1}', '{$Display2}', '{$userlevel}', '{$type}')");
    $subject = "Membership Confirmation";
    $message = "Hello, You have registered an account on  ";
    $from = "From: ";

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    header("location:signuppayment.php");

    }
}
      ?>

  <fieldset>
  <legend>Register</legend>
  <label>Username: <input class="text" type="text" name="username" id = "username" /></label>
 <label>Password: <input class="text" type="password" name="password" id = "password"/></label>
 <label>Email: <input class="text" type="text" name="email" id = "email" /></label>
 <label>First name: <input class="text" type="text" name="Fname" id = "Fname" /></label>
 <label>Last name: <input class="text" type="text" name="Lname" id = "Lname" /></label>
 <label>Display name 1: <input class="text" type="text" name="Display1" id = "Display1" /></label>
 <label>Display name 2: <input class="text" type="text" name="Display2" id = "Display2" /></label>

</fieldset>
<div class ="registerForm">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Comment: try to add echo line to see if the user is found .

Comment: At @Brian, you can do your two queries in one with a `join` you also don't need to run an `isset` if you are doing an `!empty`, `empty` checks if it is set. `$_SESSION['user_id']` might be opening you to a SQL injection. I also don't see where that is set...

Comment: @chris85 Ok thanks for the query advice, on the session issue, I put it in my register page which i didnt post in question. Shouldn't it recognize an active session once the user registers? `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  header("location:signuppayment.php");` this is at the end of form on register page

Comment: Yes, but `loggedin` is going to be false if `$_SESSION['user_id']` isn't set. You've tested that the session has the userid in it?

Comment: @chris85 when i log in normally, yes it works fine, its just the redirect from the register page to the confirmation page thats the problem, it doesnt make an active session once i register, i have to log in to make it show information.

Comment: Is the session set one the page you are redirected to? Any errors reported?

Comment: @chris85 you are redirected to the confirmation page and yes the errors reported are that the three pieces of info, "username, password, user level" are all undefined on confirmation page, only errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83053/discussion-between-chris85-and-brian).